# How to display a number in German culture?

Tags: c#-4.0

How to display the Number 89345.00  as 89.345,00 using string format in German culture?

Thanks.

Comment: Tim's answer will do the trick. Remember that you should only have to code for it if you want to **force** the numbers to be displayed this way - in an ASP.NET or Windows Form application, this is done automatically by the Framework.

Comment: Am asking for WPF applications

Comment: @Karthi: Renan's comment is misleading. If you want to force a specific culture you can  use the overloads of `ToString`  which support a format-provider as shown below. If you don't use them the current culture of the system is used(e.g. in ASP.NET of the system of the webserver).

Answer (score 1):

```
var deCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
string str = number.ToString("N", deCulture); // for numbers
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/5preQe)